# How should I handle TableModel updates when working with SQL?

Tags: java, sql, swing, jtable

My GUI includes a `JTable` and several forms that may trigger `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` SQL queries. Whenever it happens, I want my table to be updated accordingly. Since both the `TableModel` and the remote SQL table must be updated, there are several ways to proceed.

- **Update the SQL table first, then `SELECT` the modified data, and call `fireTableDataChanged()`.** This is what I am currently doing. It guarantees that the table and the database are perfectly synchronized. However, the `TableModel` is not updated until its data is extracted from the `ResultSet`, and it the whole thing takes between 0.5 and 1 second on average in my case. Which is not too bad, but not too good either.
- **Update both of them at the same time, modifying the `TableModel` to match what I would expect to previous method to do.** This could improve performance on the client's side, since changes would be almost instantaneous, and SQL stuff would be ran "in the background". But I feel unsure about losing sync between the table and the database, this looks like the dirty way.
- **Mix these two methods.** Perhaps quick, single-cell updates should use the second method, while `INSERT`s and `DELETE`s would require the first one? It feels inconsistent, though more efficient.
- **Is there another way?**

How should I proceed? Please share your experience on this matter.

Answer (score 1):

I like your first choice with updating `JTable` from SQL table using `SELECT`.

If you worry about 0.5-1 second pauses - you can mix first and second variant in following way: instantly update table with "expected" result, execute SQL, then `SELECT` modified data and check if it is the same as current. I think in most cases they will be the same so no updating of `JTable` will be needed, but also you get synchronized models.

Answer (score 1):

The first approach that came to my mind is to create a subclass of `AbstractTableModel`, and store the data in its private `ArrayList<?>` field. In its constructor, query the database with the data you want to show in the table.

If a row is added to the table, an `INSERT` statement with the data inserted will be fired to the DB.

If an update to a cell in the table is done, validate if the update is possible. If possible, an `UPDATE` will be fired to the DB

If a row is deleted, a `DELETE FROM` statement will be fired to the DB.

```
public class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel{

    private List<Person> dataSource;

    public MyTableModel(){
        dataSource = new ArrayList<Person>();

        //query the database then add the queried data to the dataSource, 
        //you should do it in the background, using SwingWorker
        //call fireTableRowsInserted with proper arguments
    }
    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return dataSource.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
        Object retVal = null;

        if(col == 0)dataSource.get(row).getFirstName();
        else if(col == 1)dataSource.get(row).getLastName();
        else if(col == 2)dataSource.get(row).getOccupation();

        return retVal;
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col){
        //validate if the update is possible, if yes proceed
        //update the value in the DB
        //update the value in the arraylist
        //call super.setValueAt(value, row, col);
    }

    public void addRow(Person p){
        //validate if the person is insertable, if yes proceed
        //INSERT the person to the DB
        //add the person to the arraylist
        //call fireTableRowsInserted
    }

    public void deleteRow(int row){
        //call fireTableRowsDeleted
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. **Update the SQL table first, then `SELECT` the modified data, and create a new `TableModel` using the returned `ResultSet`.** This is what I am currently doing. It guarantees that the table and the database are perfectly synchronized. However, the `TableModel` is not updated until its data is extracted from the `ResultSet`, and it the whole thing takes between 0.5 and 1 second on average in my case. Which is not too bad, but not too good either.

   - wrong idea there is more than contraproductive to create a new XxxTableModel, one XxxTableModel can be used for all views, for a few JTables/JLists notice only in the case if isn't there used RowSorter or RowFilter, then logics in code must contains filtering sorting for all JTables based on one XxxTableModel
   - for static data (StandingData) to create separate XxxTableModels
2. **Update both of them at the same time, modifying the `TableModel` to match what I would expect to previous method to do.** This could improve performance on the client's side, since changes would be almost instantaneous, and SQL stuff would be ran "in the background". But I feel unsure about losing sync between the table and the database, this looks like the dirty way.

   - no idea, basically if the value from input mask (form) are stored in Databases, JTable should be refreshed and input form ended with default value
   - could be way, but required to synchonize databases, its mirror in JTable and input mask
3. **Mix these two methods.** Perhaps quick, single-cell updates should use the second method, while `INSERT`s and `DELETE`s would require the first one? It feels inconsistent, though more efficient.

   - maybe not in context of a.m. 3 points
4. **Is there another way?**

   - yes therer are a few ways but `My GUI includes a JTable and several forms that may ...` can complicating the simple things
   - create one JFrame with

     1. JSplitPane and there could be one area for all input masks laid by CardLayout, second for JTable, only one JTable, with one XxxTableModel (you can to add StandindData in JList or another JTable on south or west/east area with intention to fill free space in the container)
     2. use BorderLayout, in center are input masks layed by CardLayout, see rest in above mentioned point 1st.
     3. add a few JTables/Lists (see for example the screens for Bloomberg or Reuters Xtra3000) to one JFrame, add JPopupMenu for these Objects with JMenuItems add, amend, delete, modify .... items in JTables/Lists, then to create only one JDialog layed by CardLayout, and contains on apps startup all input masks, then output from JPopupMenu will be contains three code lines switch to card based on source, call pack for JDialog, call setVisible(true) for JDialog, but must be wrapped into invokeLater,
     4. reset all JComponents in the input mask after data are saved in database, before setVisible(false) is called, otherwise next visibility can to flashing/refresh with value in JComponent
   - nobody guarantee that data from input masks are saved in database and correctly,

     1. e.g. there could be defined triggers, that fills value for rest of columns, then all dataflow could be asynchronous, delayed by internal database rulles
     2. data flow must be to save data to database, if PreparedStatement is executed without exception, then you can to refresh input mask to default value, next step could be to load data to XxxMableModel, and if is there popup JDialog, then now is moment to hide JDialog
5. if is there an exception, then nothing will be happened with input mask and theirs value, better and safe for user, is possible to simulating in based on, can to create an screenshot and then to report it ....

Comment: "_wrong idea there is more than contraproductive to create a new XxxTableModel_" That's right, I forgot I could use `fireTableDataChanged()` in that case. Edited.